# styling a div in css

Tags: html, css

IF there is a div say

```
 <div class="ref"><contents goes here</div>
```

1. How to specify in the css as body  of the div .Meaning

   ```
    <style>
    .ref body  {
       /* ref body contents goes here*/
     }
    </style>
   ```

   Can anything like the above be done?
2. If any one can explain the below also

   ```
    <style>
     .a  > .bb
     {
     }
    </style>
   ```

What does the above mean?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, it's not totally clear what you mean. Just using `.ref { /* CSS here */ }` will target that `div` element. If you mean adding content via CSS, it's only possible using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo slectors:

```
.ref:after {
  content: "Some text";
}
```

Note: you can't put HTML in there, only text.

---

For the second one, it looks for all elements with a class of `bb` that are direct children of class `a`. For example, it will match the `p` in this code

```
<div class="a">
  <div>something</div>
  <p class="bb">class bb</p>
</div>
```

But it won't match this:

```
<div class="a">
  <div>
      <p class="bb">class bb</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`body` is a specific HTML element. In order to style the contents of a div with a class of `ref`, your CSS selector is simply `.ref`, not `.ref body`.

The `>` in CSS is called the *child selector*. It means that the element on the right must be a child element of the one on the left. So:

`.a > .bb` would match the `bb` div here:

```
<div class="a"><div class="bb"></div></div>
```

but not here:

```
<div class="bb"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> For the first one

CSS is only for styling you elements and not for showing HTML.

> For the second on

styles all elements with class name 'bb' which are children[not descendants] of elements with class 'a'. See **[child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)**

**Ex 1**

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="bb"></div>
</div>
```

**Ex 2**

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="bb"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="bb"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Child selector will only select the first div with class 'bb' and not the inner div with class 'bb'.